# Updating a nested key value in a MongoDB collection document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this collection in my MongoDB (Atlas) database, that represents exercise logs for users:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("...") <--- Exercise ID
    exerciseName: "Bench Press",
    sets: [
      {
        _id: ObjectId("...") <--- Set ID
        weight: 100
        reps: 10
        createdAt: 1614461387587
        notes: ""
      },
      {
        // More set data objects
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    // More exercise data objects
  }
]
```

I am creating a functionality in my app that allows users to edit a set, incase they input it incorrectly. Currently, I do this by fetching the user's exercise that the set belongs to with:

```
const user = checkAuth(context);
let exerciseLog = await Exercise.findOne({
  _id: exerciseId,
  user: user.id,
  "sets._id": setId,
});
```

Which gets the correct exercise log. From there, I thought I could use the .find() function to get the set that needs editing and replace the values with new ones like so:

```
const set = exerciseLog.sets.find((set) => set.id === setId);
if (set) {
  const newSet = { ...set, weight, reps, notes };
  const setIndex = exerciseLog.sets.findIndex(
    (set) => set.id === setId
  );
  exerciseLog.sets.splice(setIndex, 1, newSet);
  await exerciseLog.save();
}
```

However, this approach once executed, does replace the values for weight, reps and notes but deletes the createdAt key entirely and changes the set id to a new one. I thought that by using the spread operator, values for the object would be retained except the ones that follow the operator? How can I implement a solution in which I keep the old id and createdAt, while updating the weight, reps and notes values in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both `find` and `update` in single query
Try this:

```js
db.Workout.updateOne(
    {
        "sets._id": ObjectId("6039709fe0c7d52970d3fa2f")
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "sets.$.weight": 101,
            "sets.$.reps": 11,
            "sets.$.notes": "Updated"
        }
    }
);
```

Mongoose:

```js
Exercise.updateOne(
    {
        "sets._id": ObjectId("6039709fe0c7d52970d3fa2f")
    },
    {
        "sets.$.weight": 101,
        "sets.$.reps": 11,
        "sets.$.notes": "Updated"
    }
).exec();
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. Is there a way to check whether the query executed, such as returning an error if it isn't executed?

Comment: it is same as other queries u have handled. use `await` or `.then().catch()`